# How many concurrent clients locust support on each slave?

Tags: load-testing, locust

I'm getting my slave processes killed when running more than 300 clients per node.
The machines are hosted in Rackspace and the configuration of each one is:

- 512MB RAM
- 1 CPU

Should I increase the memory of the machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's totally dependent on the code of your test scripts. Generally, I would say that it's more common to be limited by CPU before RAM, however in your case it sounds like it might be the Linux OOM Killer killing the processes. The reason for this could be that you have a memory leak in the test code, but it's really hard to tell without more info.

Also, on machines with only a single CPU core, you shouldn't run more than one Locust slave process.

Comment: I'm just running a client.get(...) with my script, and running only one proccess in each slave machine. The memory was the problem, I've increased the memory and the process was not killed with more clients. I think that a warning could be useful in these situations.